# MS Access Search Form need to pass values from unbound combo box to query

Tags: database, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010

I have a very simple table with about 10 columns. I have set up a search form with all unbound fields and a couple of combo boxes that reference the table on 2 columns, one for each combo box. I have been using this for these two types of criteria in my query:

1)    `Like "*" & [Forms]![Contract Search]![ContractName] & "*"`

2)    `Like IIf(IsNull([Forms]![Contract Search]![Amount]),"*",[Forms]![Contract Search]![Amount])`

Basically i have the first one setup to match anything in the text box and if left blank return all. The second one I have setup to match exact or if null return all. I want to use the second criteria logic for the combo boxes.

This works fine for the text boxes and check boxes but when I use the same format for the combo box it doesn't display anything on the query.

Combo Box Criteria I am using:

```
IIf(IsNull([Forms]![Contract Search]![Project]),"*",[Forms]![Contract Search]![Project])
```

even a simple criteria:[Forms]![Contract Search]![Project] does not work with the combobox.. if i convert it to a text box it works..

The values show up fine in the combo box in the search form, but they dont seem to pass the selection to the query. I dont understand what I am doing wrong. These are all unbound controls. I am using Microsoft Access 2010.

Comment: I think we should try to debug what you currently have. Create a new query. In design view, in Field: write => `[Forms]![Contract Search]![YourComboBoxName]` .. Then, go to your form. Select a value in the combobox. Go back to the query and run it. Do you get a value?

Comment: No it does not work.. I created a new database with just one column in the table, a form with a unbound drop down box which gets the values from the table and a run query button which runs a macro to run the query, and a query on the column of the table with criteria [Forms]![Search]![ComboBox] and nothing displays..

Comment: I would check the bound column number of the combo box. In the immediate window, `? [Forms]![Contract Search]![Project]` to check which column is actually being returned by the combo. You may be mixing up display text and bound value - `Like 16*` instead of `Like Smith*`, which is not possible in just a textbox.

Comment: Thx pteranodon!! yeah it was the bound column.. it was set to 1 so it was looking at the ID.. MS should make it default to 2!!